# where to run commands on mysql

Tags: mysql

I work on a java project using mysql as database, at some level I needed to increase  the value of max_allowed_packet variable, I checked in the net but I can't find my.cnf or my.ini.
So I need to run some recommended command such as `set global max_allowed_packet=33554432` but I do not know where to find the terminal to do that.
I am using mySql 8.0 on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The default location for `mysql.exe` is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`.

In the same directory you will find `mysqladmin.exe`, which gives a clue about where `my.cnf` of `my.ini` is:

> mysqladmin | findstr "my.ini"

If the `my.cnf` or `my.ini` if not found at above locations, it is probably in the `datadir`

> mysqladmin variables -u root -p | findstr datadir

Answer (score 0):

You can configure using  MySql Workbench.Navigate  to menu items Server-->Status or System Variables.
Search for max_allowed_packet

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to log into your MySQL instance, typically you would do this from the command line...
`mysql -u root -p`

That gets you to a MySQL prompt.  From there you can run a `SET` command

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

```
SET variable = expr [, variable = expr] ...

variable: {
    user_var_name
  | param_name
  | local_var_name
  | {GLOBAL | @@GLOBAL.} system_var_name
  | [SESSION | @@SESSION. | @@] system_var_name
}
```

In your case that command would be `SET global max_allowed_packet=33554432;`